# How do I send C++ array data to MATLAB via the MATLAB Engine

Tags: c++, arrays, matlab

I have an array of line points that I need to plot using the line command in MATLAB. I can successfully initiate the engine and create an array with set values and plot from this array. However I have run into frustration after frustration with creating an array in the engine from an array already created in my program.

MATLAB's website for creating an array is [here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/apiref/matlab.data.arrayfactory.html).

It is missing an example for the one thing I need which is creating an array! My latest code attempt to send the data is as follows::

```
#include "MatlabDataArray.hpp"
#include "MatlabEngine.hpp"
constexpr auto ArrayLength = 400;
double OPAx[ArrayLength];
double OPAy[ArrayLength];
int OPAi = 0;

auto Xplotdata = factory.createArray<double>({(unsigned int)(OPAi)},  std::begin(OPAx), std::end(OPAx) );
auto Yplotdata = factory.createArray<double>({(unsigned int)(OPAi)},  std::begin(OPAy), std::end(OPAy) );
std::cout << "OPAi:" << (unsigned int)OPAi << '\n';
matlabPtr->eval(u"figure");
matlabPtr->setVariable(u"Xplot", std::move(Xplotdata));
matlabPtr->setVariable(u"Yplot", std::move(Yplotdata));

for (i = 0; i < (OPAi - 2) ; i++)
    {
    u16string output1 = u"Xplot(" + to_u16string(i + 1) + u":" + to_u16string(i + 2) + u")";
    u16string output2 = u"Yplot(" + to_u16string(i + 1) + u":" + to_u16string(i + 2) + u")";
    u16string output = u"line(" + output1 + u"," + output2 + u")";
    matlabPtr->eval(output);
    }
```

- `OPAi`: int containing the length of the arrays
- `OPAx`: double array containing x values
- `OPAy`: double array containing y values

It begins by creating the arrays in the MATLAB Engine then assigning them to variables `Xplot` and `Yplot` in MATLAB. It then iterates through plotting lines for each x and y value.

The code seemed to run successfully once and now it returns an error: Access violation reading location 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF. I understand I am giving the array pointers to the memory locations of the arrays and copying from there but can't figure out why it is producing this error. My call to the locations using `std::end(OPAx)` and `std::begin(OPAx)` might be to blame but those are the only way I have found to call the memory locations in the format the `createArray` function likes. Any help in solving this issue is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please read [mre]. There is a reason we ask for a reproducible example: describing code is much less effective than showing code. What is `OPAx`? A "double array" can be so many different things in C++...

Comment: I would suggest you don't build strings to evaluate in MATLAB, instead call `matlabPtr->feval()`, as described [in the documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/call-matlab-functions-from-c-1.html) (this page, by the way, also includes examples of creating arrays!). -- The [`feval` documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/apiref/matlab.engine.matlabengine.html#bvkfuut-8) also has examples.